# C++ cannot convert 'type' to 'type*'

Tags: c++, types

getting this error in my code `error: cannot convert 'Aircrafts' to 'Aircrafts*'`

All I am trying to do is add a class record into a vector.

it is a c++ code and using -ansi -Wall -pedantic

it is bit annoying me. Hope somebody can help. Here is my code:

error is given for this line `temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Scenic", "Piper Arrow", 3, 120, 0, 0);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Aircrafts
{
   public:
      string category;
      string aircraft;

   public: 

      Aircrafts () { 
         category = "";
         aircraft = "";         
      }

      Aircrafts (string f_cat, string airc) {
         category = f_cat;
         aircraft = airc;
      }      
}

void main()
{

   vector <Aircrafts> aircraft_list;

   Aircrafts *temp_aircraft;

   temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts;
   temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
   aircraft_list.push_back(*temp_aircraft);
}
```

Comment: For learning more on basics like this, you might want to pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix the error in levels of indirection, you can replace

```
temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts;
temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

with

```
temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

That's the correct syntax for calling a constructor with parameters. However, this creates a memory leak.

You do not need `new` there at all - you can do everything on a single line without using a `temp_aircraft` pointer:

```
aircraft_list.push_back(Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz"));
```

Comment: And even if you _did_ use a `temp_Aircraft`, you still wouldn't need to make it a pointer: `Aircrafts temp_Aircraft{"Abc", "Xyz"};`

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning an `Aircrafts` object into a pointer to `Aircrafts`. This doesn't work.

Looking at your code, you don't need any dynamic allocation (= `new`) at all. Just do this:

```
void main()
{

   vector <Aircrafts> aircraft_list;

   aircraft_list.push_back(Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for pointers

```
Aircrafts temp_aircraft("Abc", "Xyz");
aircraft_list.push_back(temp_aircraft);
```

Why do beginners *love* pointers?

EDIT I rest my case, the OP picked the answer that continued to use pointers, despite every other answer telling them that pointers were unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

First you declare `temp_aircraft` as a pointer to `Aircrafts`, which you then initialize using `new` correctly. However, you *then* try to assign a non-pointer object to the pointer.

There is no need for pointers here, just create the object and push it into the container in one go:

```
aircraft_list.push_back(Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz"));
```

This will work with your class even if you haven't defined an explicit copy-assignment operator (the compiler will create a simple for you). But you might want to learn about [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code,

```
temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

should be

```
temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

And remember to include semicolon at the end of the class.

```
class Aircrafts
{
   .....
}; // <-- semicolon here
```

Comment: Good spot on the semicolon, bad idea to introduce a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts;
temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

you should do:

```
temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

constructor Aircrafts() gives you Aircrafts object, meantime temp_aircraft is `Aircrafts *`

---

P.S. also you have memory leak problem. All what you have allocated with `new` you must free with `delete` when you don't need it anymore;
You can do it like:

```
   Aircrafts *temp_aircraft;

   temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts;
   temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
   aircraft_list.push_back(*temp_aircraft);
   delete temp_aircraft;
```

or may be you don't need a pointer at all. Same result you can achieve with one line:

```
   aircraft_list.push_back( Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz") );
```

Answer (score 1):

no need for a temporary object.

```
int main()
{
   vector <Aircrafts> aircraft_list;
   aircraft_list.emplace_back("Abc", "Xyz");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`temp_aircraft` is a pointer, so when you try to do

```
temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Scenic", "Piper Arrow", 3, 120, 0, 0);
```

you are trying to use the assignment operator to assign a Aircrafts to `temp_aircarft`

You can just use this constructor when you say new:

```
   temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

(or whatever the line really is that gives the error)

Of course, when you then do

```
aircraft_list.push_back(*temp_aircraft);
```

you are going to forget to delete the pointer. As other answers say, you can (and *should*) do this without pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line: `temp_aircraft = Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");`

WHen you write `Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz")`, you create an object of the class Aircrafts, and you try to affect it to a variable of type Aircrafts* (pointer to Aircrafts). If you want to create a pointer, use the operator `new`, like this :

```
temp_aircraft = new Aircrafts("Abc", "Xyz");
```

If you don't want a pointer, create your variable with the Aircraft type, like this:

```
Aircrafts temp_aircraft;
```

Here, you mix the two ways, that's why it doesn't work.